# Why use Sorted Set instead of List Redis

Tags: list, redis, set, sortedset, zset

Why would I use a `redis sorted set` of articles sorted by unix timestamp over a `redis list` and pushing elements onto it. They seem to offer the same end results. One thing I notice is with a `redis sorted set` you can do intersections with other sets and zsets

Comment: 1) With a sorted set you are guaranteed that articles are unique - you don't get that with a list. 2) With a list, you are sorted by order of pushing onto the list, whereas with a set you can sort by other criteria - e.g. popularity.

Answer (score 11):

Depends on your usage afterward.

Sorting a ZSET by the insertion order, and using a list can look similar, but there are many differences. Here are a few:

1. LIST can have duplicates.
2. Checking in an element exists is very efficient in ZSET, but very expansive in a LIST (especially if the element is not there).
3. Fetching non-edges elements from a LIST can be slow (depends on the size of the LIST and on the distance of the object from one of the edges).
4. LIST is most efficient when working with the edges (L/R PUSH/POP).
5. ZSET has the added functionality of unions and intersects, and you can sort by any other score/weight.
6. In ZSET, the score can be updated later on, and the order will change.

In general, look at the API that each datatype provides, and choose the one that gives you the best results for what you need (other than being sorted by insertion time).

Answer (score 4):

The sorted set ensure that the key is unique. If you want to do something complex. For example, every time a user login, you add the userid to a sorted set. And there is a backend service read the sorted set and update the user's information and action habbit. It can save a lot of work if you are using sorted set.

What's more, if the user is a premium paid member, you can set the score of his or her id higher, and refresh this user's habbit match earlier.